# Какое минимальное число слагаемых потребуется, чтобы представить число 9002 в таком виде?

Tags: математика, олимпиада

**Задача :**

Число 2020 можно представить в виде суммы четырех различных чисел, каждое из которых записывается хотя бы двумя цифрами и все
цифры в них одинаковые:
2020 = 1111 + 777 + 99 + 33.
А какое минимальное число слагаемых потребуется, чтобы представить число 9002 в таком виде?

**Мое решение :**

9002=4444+999+888+777+666+555+222+99+88+77+66+55+44+22

получается здесь **ответ 14 слагаемых**

правильно ли я решил задачу?

Comment: Эмм... У Вас 14 слагаемых...

Comment: @EOF да )не заметил)но ответ 14 получается или по другому решается?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, меньше чем 14 - никак. Задача решается за не более чем 10 минут набрасывания кода исчерпывающего перебора и 6-7 секунд этого самого перебора машиной. У вас же не более чем 2^27 вариантов - это нынешним машинам на один зуб.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int v[] = {
    11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,
    111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,
    1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999
};

int test(unsigned int f, int& count)
{
    int sum = 0, idx = 0; count = 0;
    while(f)
    {
        if (f&1)
        {
            sum += v[idx];
            count++;
        }
        f >>= 1;
        idx++;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int M = 0; int cnt = 1000;
    for(unsigned int m = 0; m < 0x8000000; ++m)
    {
        int count;
        if (test(m,count) == 9002)
        {
            if (count < cnt)
            {
                cnt = count;
                M = m;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << M << "  " << cnt << endl;
}
```

Расшифровку `M` в список чисел сделайте сами...

Comment: значит правильным ответом является число 14?

Comment: Да, именно так. И для 2020 - ответ 4 :)

Comment: ой поспорил бы я. Да и код мне не нравится) Сейчас свой ответ напишу.

Comment: @pavel Только не забудьте слово **различных**. Я сначала на нем прокололся - и вышло что 2020 = 999+999+22. Хорошо, что еще раз перечитал условие... А код... ну что вы хотите от разовой поделки, на коленке писанной? :)

Comment: @Harry я тоже решал когда задание решал другими сопсобами решил так поначалу:

Comment: 7777+444+7*99+88.

Comment: и получил ответ 10 ) но потом заметил слово **различных**

Comment: @Harry а хотя в целом всё равно. Ответ 14 такой же, замена одного вида рюкзака на другой ничего глобально не меняет. Кстати, может вопрос как дубликат закрыть?

Comment: @pavel почему это дубликат??

Comment: @gaak2309 потому что задача о рюкзаке не один раз разбиралась. Код ровно тот же самый что и везде.

Comment: Дубликак какого вопроса? я не так хорошо ориентируюсь и помню все вопросы :)

Comment: @pavel при чем тут это? такого же точно не было, а во вторых тут я даже решение свое привел. Это дубликатом не является